# Reading from an input file that has lines with no periods at the end (and numbers)

Tags: file, input, prolog

Making a hexadecimal 16x16 sudoku solver. I started with an input file that looks like this:

```
1....c3...5....a
.438.0d5..fab...
.b9..7.f..d.13..
.7...9.e.4....60
4e...f..8.....bc
.6d.9..87..124.f
.2.13....d...5..
..8.6......50.9.
.c.4e......f.2..
..b...4....83.a.
3.172..b4..c.60.
f8.....9..a...cb
7d....f.6.1...e.
..6e.n..2.7..0d.
...984..5c3.ab1.
8....2...0e....3
```

The periods represent the unknown squares. So I've been trying to just read in the input file using this program:

```
main :-
    open('input.txt', read, ID),
    repeat,
    read(ID, X),
    write(X), nl,
    X == end_of_file,
    close(ID).
```

Whenever I run that, I get the error:

`input.txt:1:1: Syntax error: Operator expected`

I believe I am encountering two issues that I would like help with.

1. Does every line of the input have to end in a period for you to be able to read in line-by-line into Prolog, or not?
2. Are are you also able to read in from a file that includes numbers? If so, how?

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is do to the fact that [read/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=read/2) reads [terms](http://www.dai.ed.ac.uk/groups/ssp/bookpages/quickprolog/node5.html), e.g.

```
dog.
cat.
hello.
```

If you are using SWI-Prolog then don't use section [4.20 Term reading and writing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=termrw) use section [4.19 Primitive character I/O](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chario) which has predicates like [get_char/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=get_char/2)

So the fix to your current problem is to change

```
read/2
```

to

```
get_char/2
```

```
main :-
    open('input.txt', read, ID),
    repeat,
    %read(ID, X),
    get_char(ID,X),
    write(X), nl,
    X== end_of_file,
    close(ID).
```

When run

```
?- main.
1
.
.
.

...

.
.
.
3
end_of_file
true ;
ERROR: stream `<stream>(00000000031BB760)' does not exist
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] get_char(<stream>(00000000031BB760),_14142)
ERROR:    [8] main at c:/...so_question_01.pl:10
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

So this will fix the error for the question you asked. You now have a different problem that is another question and normally on StackOverflow you would be required to ask another question.

Since you did not know you had a second error in your program and trying to figure it out can be challenging to someone just learning Prolog as it is related to backtracking here is the quick fix.

```
main :-
    open('input.txt', read, ID),
    repeat,
    %read(ID, X),
    get_char(ID,X),
    write(X), nl,
    X == end_of_file,  !,   % Notice the cut (!) at the end of this line
    close(ID).
```

When run

```
?- main.
1
.
.
.

...

.
.
.
3
end_of_file
true.
```